# PHP if statement with PHP mail()

Tags: if-statement, php

I just added a phone number input to a contact form and I want to make it so if the user chooses to input their phone number in our form I want to append some text + the phone number to the body of the email being sent out with the php mail() function. If the user leaves the phone number input blank I don't want the extra text.

This script worked perfectly until I inserted the if statement with the text I want appended. Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$number = $_REQUEST['number'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

   $to = "test@test.com"; 
   $email_subject = "Message from test.com";
   $email_body = "$message";

   $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

   mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body if ($number != "") { echo "Patient Phone Number: $number";},$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Please turn [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) on in your config!

Comment: Watch out! Chuck Norris can mess up your mail server by passing weird data to $headers. Don't forget to validate incoming data if you are not doing already.

Comment: @AyeshK I'm not validating for that yet actually, do you have any links that can push me in the right direction for that kind of thing?

Comment: @AyeshK Nevermind, I looked around and I think I'm covered here, I'm validating a fair amount on name and email : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something more along the lines of this:

```
if($number != ""){
  $email_body .= "Patient Phone Number: $number";
}

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Comment: $email_body is already defined by the $message variable, is there an easy way to add two variables together? So it's basically the $message + the Patient Phone Number thing but only when the number is inputted?

Comment: Yes, the `if` statement I added is essentially doing this. If you mean simpler in terms of less lines of code, then I supposed you could short the if statement like so: `if($number != "") $email_body .= "Patient Phone Number: $number";`

Comment: Oh OK I think I understand, so .= allows you to add to a variable?

Comment: @DannyCooper the `.=` (note the dot) operator concatenates the two string together

Comment: as @Ben said, yes the `.=` operator will append the text to the `$email_body` string.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use if-statements inside function arguments, therefore use:

```
<?php

  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

  $to = "test@test.com"; 
  $email_subject = "Message from test.com";
  $email_body = "$message";

  /**
   * Append number to email body (.= adds text after the previously defined $email_body -string)
   */
  if ($number != "") { 
    $email_body .= "Patient Phone Number: $number";
  }

  $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove if statement out of mail function to assign it as a variable then send it to the mail function.